# Clickable Text + Image using TextView in Android

Tags: android, spannablestring

How to put an clickable `image` in between `string` using a single `TextView`.

[image]

Using `SpannableString`, I am able to color part of string. But how to add a colored image? Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for a single `TextView` element. `TextView`s are not meant to contain images in the middle of them.

You can, however, add drawable resources to the top, right/start, left/end, or bottom of a given `TextView` by leveraging the `drawableTop`, `drawableBottom`, etc. attributes.  But again, no way of adding an image in the middle of a `TextView` by using only one of them.

If you really want that specific effect, I would group a few XML components into any `ViewGroup` like a `ConstraintLayout` to get exactly what you want; e.g.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_part_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="first part of the text"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_part_1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_part_2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_part_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="first part of the text"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if `text_part_2` has more text?

Comment: What do you mean by more text? You can add as much text as you need on either side. The idea behind this answer is to showcase how you can have an image in the middle of two pieces of text.  Te text contents should be mostly irrelevant, meaning that you can have whatever you wan on either side without a problem.